# Serial/SSH Communication

Tags: linux, ssh, python

I have a Linux module.

I need to receive messages via  SSH and transmit them using serial and vice versa.

Basically I want a pipe or a gateway between a SSH and Serial device.

Can anyone provide some guidance as to how it can be done.

Comment: use ssh tunnel.

Comment: What is a "Linux module"? Do you have a consistent device name? What have you tried so far? What didn't work? You might start by looking at minicom or setserial and raw device access.

Comment: I am using the the Synapse E10. I have been able to establish a ssh connection to a remote host. I now just want help to forward the messages from remote host to a client on the serial port of E10.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a command for ssh to run on the remote system by appending it to the end of the command line. If your 'print to serial' app/module takes input on stdin, you can simply do this:

```
ssh user@host "print_to_serial_command"
```

That will connect your ssh session to the stdin/stdout of the remote process, so you can pipe your input to the ssh command, use a here document, etc.